# Does CIFS / SMB use multiple connections?

Tags: windows, smb, cifs

Does CIFS / SMB use multiple connections?

I am wondering this because transferring multiple files on the same computer seems to be limited to one NIC link and not more.  I have a 10G on the client and multiple LACP nics on the server.  You would think that a multiple socket connection could allow you to saturate all the LACP nics.

Can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441901.aspx

Seems to indicate a single NetBIOS TCP connection per SMB / CIFS session.

If this is true, obviously this is a horrible design.  Not allowing out of band file transfers seems crazy.

Comment: for modern implementations, on the server side, SMB transfers over 445 exclusively. you can try disabling NETBios over TCP/IP, but I believe that it would use UDP, and the streams may not play nicely with your aggregated links.

Comment: The server side may be 445 but will the client use multiple sockets per session for transfers or does the client use a single multiplexed TCP connection?

Comment: client connections come from an unused ports above 49000.

Comment: That would only make sense if it was using UDP because then you would create one listener port per client.  This is how VoIP works. It creates UDP ports for each data stream.

Comment: well, my netstat is showing a connection from localhost tcp/59800 to my samba servers tcp/445, even though I have 4 documents open on its shares, and a video playing to boot. the connection is made by the system process (PID 4). then I connect to my NAS, and see a second connection to it, over tcp between client 60185 and NAS 445. you can use `netstat -an | findstr <server IP>` in powershell to see the connections you have to your server if you are curious.

Comment: I probably should have done that before.  I can download 2 files and upload 2; still only one TCP connection.

Comment: TCP is most efficient when a single connection is multiplexed, so that's how SMB works.

Answer (score 2):

The multiple connections feature (aka - multichannel) is available from SMB 3.0. So that it will work, for instance, between W8 and W2k12.