# Limiting number of simultaneous users to a shared folder in windows

Tags: windows, networking, file-transfer, file-sharing

This is regarding the option in advanced sharing dialog of windows while enabling folder sharing.

```
"limit the number of simultaneous users to"
```

What action causes the OS to take into account as simultaneous access and which action would decrement the access counter? A copy operation/windows explorer session opened to the shared folder?

I tried to check it myself restricting the counter to 2, opened the shared folder on one m/c and asking another user to access it. The other user got access denied, with message saying that simultaneous sharing is limited. on increasing the counter to 3 didnt help either.

When i increased it to 10, user 2 could access the folder.
So its not clear how this limit is applied.

Basically i need to make sure not to many users are copying files simultaneously so as to not cripple the network of the m/c hosting the folder.

I cant seem to find this information on googling.

[image]

Comment: A quick raw test: `wmic path Win32_Share get AllowMaximum,MaximumAllowed,Name,Type`

Comment: It's purpose was to comply with licensing conditions of maximum connections allowed in the nineteen eighties and nineteen nineties.

Comment: Documentation doesnt detail it either :( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753521(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running? Might dictate what version of SMB your using which may yield a better answer

Comment: What do you mean by m/c? Master Computer?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one user could be opening multiple 'sessions' & if that is the case Windows is worded poorly since it explicitly states 'users'. Right-click Computer or Start Menu (depends on your Windows version), Computer Management, System Tools, Shared Folders, & look at Sessions. I'm not in a position to test this & 15min with Google didn't yield any details either. Outstanding questions IF this is true:

- What actions causes a client to use multiple sessions?
- Can you tweak something in Windows to force it to adhere to the user limit instead of the 'session' limit?

Below are links with high-level technical info on Windows SMB file share architecture. I saw a result about a [TCP Half Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) which apparently happens when one side of the connection fails & the other one doesn't know so keeps it open. PC2 user2 has share open but something crashs on that PC so it starts a new session & server doesn't disconnect old session since it didn't know it crashed. Not sure if thats how it works, but the sessions should provide insight & control.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/direct-hosting-of-smb-over-tcpip
- [Does CIFS / SMB use multiple connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/888513/does-cifs-smb-use-multiple-connections)
- https://thinksystem.lenovofiles.com/storage/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsmbcifs_configuration_guide_for_microsoft%2F514BE8CE-FD6D-4944-B4DB-C75578E358B7_.html
- https://www.dell.com/community/Isilon/Large-number-of-SMB-connections-from-a-single-client/td-p/7101305
- [https://www.google.com/search?q="limit+the+number+of+simultaneous+users+to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22limit+the+number+of+simultaneous+users+to%22)
  [https://www.google.com/search?q="allow+this+number+of+users"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22allow+this+number+of+users%22)
- [https://www.google.com/search?q="limit+the+number+of+simultaneous+users+to"+site:social.technet.microsoft.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22limit+the+number+of+simultaneous+users+to%22+site:social.technet.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 1):

There are alternative means for setting this limit, which might work better.

- Set the value in
  *Computer Management > System Tools > Shared Folders > Shares*,
  right-click the share, select Properties and set User limit. Press OK to finish.

  [image]
- In a Command Prompt (cmd) run as Administrator, use the command:

  ```
    net share <sharename> /users:<number>
  ```